# Error 404 When Accessing Elide Standalone Web API Running on Port 8080

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, elide

I'm trying to run a simple Elide-based Web API:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ElideStandalone elide = new ElideStandalone(new Settings());
        elide.start();
    }
}
```

Although running `mvn package exec:java` work, accessing the port, `http://localhost:8080` always return a Jetty 404 error.  What could be wrong with the settings?

```
public class Settings implements ElideStandaloneSettings {
    @Override
    public Properties getDatabaseProperties() {
        Properties dbProps;
        try {
            dbProps = new Properties();
            dbProps.load(
                    Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("dbconfig.properties")
            );
            return dbProps;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getPort() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(System.getenv("PORT"))
                .map(Integer::valueOf)
                .orElse(8080);
    }

    // ...

}
```

Then when accessed from: `GET http://localhost:8080/api/users` it throws *"Unknown collection users"* error. What could be wrong with the model mapping?

For the full source: https://github.com/cyberquarks/pg-elide-standalone-starter

My goal is to be able to access the Swagger UI and access the `User` and `UserProfile` model API endpoints